# How to properly exit from an interactive SSH session with forwarded ports launched via Python?

Tags: python, ssh

I'm trying to write a wrapper Python script that automatically sets up port forwards to a remote host based on some parameters, and then gives me that shell. Everything works great, up until I want to exit the shell -- at which point, the session hangs and never returns me back to Python. Here's a toy example that does the same thing:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('ssh -L8080:localhost:80 fooserver.net')
user@fooserver.net password:
[fooserver.net]$ hostname
fooserver.net
[fooserver.net]$ exit
(hangs)
```

I believe this has something to do with the forwarded TCP port being in "TIME_WAIT" and keeping the SSH session alive until it closes, because this doesn't happen if I never request that forwarded port locally. What's the right way to handle this? Can I capture the "exit" from inside Python and then kill the os.system() pipe or something?